# Objective C Block within Block generates Leak. How can I solve it?

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, block, objective-c-blocks

Why does this code generates a leak? How could it be solved?

This is the original call:

```
NSString * url = @"https://theserverurl/user/login" ;
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"login":@"the-email@mail.com", @"password":@"encrypted-password"} ;


[[BackEndAPI sharedManager] NSURLSessionOperation: @"POST" url: url parameters: parameters success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, id responseObject) {
   // Success
} failure:^(IDLEngineError *engineError) {
   // Failure        
}] ;
```

This is the singleton which handles the NSURL request:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *) NSURLSessionOperation:(NSString *) restOperation
                                             url:(NSString *)url
                                      parameters:(id)parameters
                                         success:(void (^)(NSMutableURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, id responseObject))success
                                         failure:(void (^)(IDLEngineError *))failure {


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    __weak id weakSelf = self ;

    // POST
    if ([restOperation isEqualToString:@"POST"]) {

        NSError *error;
        NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: sessionConfig ];

        // Create the request
        __block NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url ] ];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"] ;
        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
        NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: parameters options: 0 error:&error];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        // Perform operation
        NSURLSessionDataTask * task = [session dataTaskWithRequest: request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            // This generates a leak!!!!
            success(request, nil, nil) ;

        }] ;

        [task resume] ;

    }


    return nil ;


}
```

Please take a look to the leaked app on GitHub:

https://github.com/arkyxperience/myleakedapp

Find also here the report (screenshot) coming from Instruments:

[image: Result of Instruments - Leaks]

Comment: 1. __block is not needed, that is for sure. 2. are you sure there is nothing in the success block that would generate the leak? 3. Please double check if your "simplification" didn't remove important piece of code.

Comment: Success block should be straight forward, not sure whether that's the issue. I've uploaded the app to GitHub so you can see the simplification didn't remove the problematic piece of code as the leak remains.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the leak is with NSURLSessionDataTask. If you isolate the following piece of code, the leak will remain:

```
NSString * url = @"https://theserverurl/user/login" ;
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"login":@"the-email@mail.com", @"password":@"encrypted-password"} ;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSError *error;
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: sessionConfig ];


// Create the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url ] ];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"] ;
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: parameters options: 0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

// Perform operation
NSURLSessionDataTask * task = [session dataTaskWithRequest: request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

}] ;

[task resume] ;
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Try to remove more and more code, at some point it will stop leaking, then tell the line

Comment: The leak is here: "NSURLSessionDataTask * task = ..." It looks like the library has a leak. If you don't perform the task, the leak disappears.

Comment: You mean without `[task resume] ;`?

Comment: In theory, if you comment [task resume], the task shouldn't be triggered and the leak shouldn't happen. But the leak remains only by commenting [task resume]!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, i tried your github code, looks like there is no leak. What object is leaking after all? To test this code please add restoration id to your controller. In this code dealloc is being triggered even tho i don't use weak to call controller. So controller is not leaking, complete block does not have a retain loop.  Don't see anything that can leak in `NSURLSessionOperation:`. So what exactly is leaking?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString * url = @"https://google.com" ;
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"login":@"the-email@mail.com", @"password":@"encrypted-password"} ;
    [[BackEndAPI sharedManager] NSURLSessionOperation: @"POST" url: url parameters: parameters success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse * response, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"finish");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.view.window.rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        });

    } failure:^(NSError * error) {
        NSLog(@"fail");
    }];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Did dealloc");
}
```

Comment: I don't know what's leaking, but the controller can still call dealloc and have a leak. Use instruments - leaks and you will see how calling the block produces a leak with your code. You will get the same output I got on the screenshot I provided from instruments.